# Calculate and display the sum, the count and the average of the all the entered numbers

Tags: python

```
    print("Enter some number (9999 is for exit): ")

count = 0
sum = 0.0
number = 1

while number != 9999:
    number = int(input("-> "))
    sum = sum + number
    count += 1

if count == 0:
    print("Input some numbers")
else:
    print("Average of the above numbers are: ", ((sum-9999) / (count-1)))
    print("Sum of the above numbers is :", sum-9999)
```

'''
The average and sum can work properly but just don't know how to display the total entered numbers that the user input?
'''

Comment: Total value of numbers is the `sum` that your code is calculating and printing. What else are you looking for

Comment: Avoid using `sum` as a variable. `sum` is a built in function inside python, once you use it, you shadow the function..

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
print(number)
```

To print the user input.